# Dynamic root element marshaling failed in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, marshalling

I have below XML ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<META_1>
<row num="1"><symbol>ABC</symbol></row>
<row num="2"><symbol>XYZ</symbol></row>
</META_1>
```

and I created XSD out of it , which has created xmlrootelement as "META1"

like ,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "META_1Type", propOrder = {
"rows"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "META_1")
public class META_1 {
```

It works/parse fine when I run with above xml file, but didnt work when new XML come with root element changed as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<META_2>
<row num="1"><symbol>ABC</symbol></row>
<row num="2"><symbol>XYZ</symbol></row>
</META_2>
```

Is there any way to handle it in while generating XSD from XML file.(generated XSD file with the help of inbuilt feature of IntelliJ)

tried other jaxb dynamic binding , but didnt work for me. expecting any solution with same.

Comment: Did you change the XMLType to META_2?

Comment: no, every day I will gone a receive new file which has new root element. So I cant create new XSD for every new XML.

Comment: The class name and the type must match.  Why do you think you are creating a new XSD?  You do not have a schema (an XSD file).